# Is it possible to calculate torque using strain gauges on a rotating shaft?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

I am currently designing a torque sensor and am looking into the ability to use strain gauges as a instrument to measure strain and calculate torque.

The current setup is two motors connected via a shaft. One of these motors will provide a torque and spin, while the other opposes and acts as a resistance.

[image: strain gauges on a rotating shaft]

The strain gauges will be placed at opposing 45° angles to each other, one will measure the positive strain while the other will measure the negative (as shown in the image above).

[image: Wheatstone Bridge example]

The gauges will be wired using a Wheatstone bridge, this will provide a voltage output and seems to be the recommended method of getting an output.

How is this Vout translated to a strain and/or is a torque value calculated? 
The end goal is to calculate a torque from the strain gauges.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque_sensor

Comment: Certainly doable, but difficult because (1) the strain-gauge signal conditioning must rotate with the shaft and (2) unless your data-acquisition setup also rotates, you need a way to transmit the data. Strongly suggest you use four active gauges and a hollow/thin-wall shaft to get a stronger signal. Don't even think about slip-rings for the low-level signals, unless you want lots of frustration!